# Java Android Sample Project NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am working on learning to work with  NFC and simply going through the example project contained in the Android package download. When I go to run the application, I encounter a

**09-12 04:51:41.548: W/dalvikvm(336): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/example/android/nfc/record/UriRecord;**

Anyone encountered the same problem, which seems to be around this method in the NDefMessageParser class.

```
public static List<ParsedNdefRecord> getRecords(NdefRecord[] records) 
{
    List<ParsedNdefRecord> elements = new ArrayList<ParsedNdefRecord>();
    for (NdefRecord record : records) {
        if (UriRecord.isUri(record)) {
            elements.add(UriRecord.parse(record));
        } else
        if (TextRecord.isText(record)) {
            elements.add(TextRecord.parse(record));
        } else if (SmartPoster.isPoster(record)) {
            elements.add(SmartPoster.parse(record));
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

[image: Picture below shows that data was passed in as parameter to the method call.]

Comment: Using any external `.jar` file?

Comment: Your jar doesnt seem to be in the class path..

Comment: The external Jar is referenced. How do I ensure it is in the classpath please?

Comment: Add it to the libs project directory